# Right way to implement SourceInitialized in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, out-of-memory, hwnd

Recently I working on WPF application where I was getting exception related to Out of memory error.
Here is the exception :

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
   at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean enableRenderTarget, Nullable`1 channelSet)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

In above I can see HwndTarget exception , in my application I have implemented SourceInitialized where I used below code

```
        void myClass_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Log.Info("myClass_SourceInitialized ");
            System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source =                        System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.FromHwnd(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
            source.AddHook(new System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
            var ss = source.CompositionTarget;
            ss.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
            Log.Info(ss.TransformFromDevice);
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
            {
                handled = true;
            }

            if (msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
            {
                int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
                if (command == SC_MOVE)
                {
                    handled = true;
                }
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

I want to understand what is the exact use of above code and is the exception i got is related to code ?

Comment: The exception is related to your machine running out of memory.  It could be the application or it could be another application that is using a lot of memory, or you just didn't purchase a lot of memory for your machine.  You could increase the Virtual memory which uses disk for memory when you run out of memory.  See : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-virtual-memory-size-windows-10?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this exception is very misleading and most probably **NOT** related to your machine running out of memory or your code!

Here are the various root causes that have triggered this exception in our code base over the decades:

- faulty VGA / GPU drivers
- faulty scanner drivers
- a bug in BitDefender virus scanner (we got hit with dozens of support cases in 2022/02), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/698987/dot-net-out-of-memory-exception-bit-defender
- PNG images with embedded Photoshop ICC profiles
- (almost 0% chance) WPF bug

Hope this helps.